# How Linux kernel selects the source IP of outgoing data packets?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ip, curl

I have multiple IP addresses assigned to a network interface, each corresponding to a different outbound IP.

> :~# curl --interface 112.73.59.255 ip.sb
> 157.119.73.25

Using the above command, I observed that the returned public IP was not the expected 112.73.59.255 but rather 157.119.73.25.

A tcpdump packet capture revealed that the actual source IP in the transmitted packets was 157.119.73.25.

Why does using the `curl --interface` switch not use the IP address specified (112.73.59.255)? What potential reasons could lead to this phenomenon?

**Additional Information:**

Outpuf of tcpdump:

```
root@ecs3ccc8a9bc987:~# tcpdump -i any host ip.sb 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
18:09:12.298128 IP 157.119.73.25.12769 > 104.26.13.31.http: Flags [S], seq 3876101966, win 42340, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 11], length 0
18:09:12.301316 IP 104.26.13.31.http > 157.119.73.25.12769: Flags [S.], seq 4171085408, ack 3876101967, win 64240, options [mss 1400,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 13], length 0
18:09:12.301354 IP 157.119.73.25.12769 > 104.26.13.31.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 21, length 0
18:09:12.301574 IP 157.119.73.25.12769 > 104.26.13.31.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:70, ack 1, win 21, length 69: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
18:09:12.304574 IP 104.26.13.31.http > 157.119.73.25.12769: Flags [.], ack 70, win 7, length 0
18:09:12.541657 IP 104.26.13.31.http > 157.119.73.25.12769: Flags [P.], seq 1:579, ack 70, win 8, length 578: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
18:09:12.541716 IP 157.119.73.25.12769 > 104.26.13.31.http: Flags [.], ack 579, win 21, length 0
18:09:12.542392 IP 157.119.73.25.12769 > 104.26.13.31.http: Flags [F.], seq 70, ack 579, win 21, length 0
18:09:12.545676 IP 104.26.13.31.http > 157.119.73.25.12769: Flags [F.], seq 579, ack 71, win 8, length 0
18:09:12.545711 IP 157.119.73.25.12769 > 104.26.13.31.http: Flags [.], ack 580, win 21, length 0
```

Output of ip route:

```
root@ecs3ccc8a9bc987:/etc/netplan#  ip route 
default via 157.119.73.1 dev ens3 proto static 
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.101.0.1 dev ens2 proto static 
10.101.0.0/24 dev ens2 proto kernel scope link src 10.101.0.48 
112.73.32.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.32.5 
112.73.34.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.34.137 
112.73.37.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.37.100 
112.73.38.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.38.105 
112.73.42.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.42.200 
112.73.47.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.47.227 
112.73.48.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.48.186 
112.73.49.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.49.100 
112.73.50.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.50.224 
112.73.52.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.52.112 
112.73.54.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.54.235 
112.73.57.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.57.7 
112.73.58.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.58.110 
112.73.59.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.59.190 
112.73.60.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.60.252 
112.73.61.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.61.104 
112.73.62.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.73.62.236 
157.119.73.0/25 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 157.119.73.25 
157.119.74.0/25 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 157.119.74.48 
157.119.74.128/25 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 157.119.74.140
```

Output of ip a:

```
root@ecs3ccc8a9bc987:~# ip a 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:0b:a7:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.101.0.48/24 brd 10.101.0.255 scope global ens2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe0b:a7e5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c3:29:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 157.119.73.25/25 brd 157.119.73.127 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 157.119.74.140/25 brd 157.119.74.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 157.119.74.48/25 brd 157.119.74.127 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.50.224/24 brd 112.73.50.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.58.110/24 brd 112.73.58.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.38.105/24 brd 112.73.38.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.57.7/24 brd 112.73.57.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.49.100/24 brd 112.73.49.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.48.186/24 brd 112.73.48.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.52.112/24 brd 112.73.52.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.42.200/24 brd 112.73.42.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.34.137/24 brd 112.73.34.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.61.104/24 brd 112.73.61.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.60.252/24 brd 112.73.60.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.54.235/24 brd 112.73.54.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.47.227/24 brd 112.73.47.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.62.236/24 brd 112.73.62.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.32.5/24 brd 112.73.32.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.37.100/24 brd 112.73.37.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.59.190/24 brd 112.73.59.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 157.119.73.27/25 brd 157.119.73.127 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 157.119.73.87/25 brd 157.119.73.127 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 157.119.74.162/25 brd 157.119.74.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.48.243/24 brd 112.73.48.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.47.232/24 brd 112.73.47.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.58.52/24 brd 112.73.58.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.52.19/24 brd 112.73.52.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.50.253/24 brd 112.73.50.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.61.192/24 brd 112.73.61.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.37.41/24 brd 112.73.37.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.52.227/24 brd 112.73.52.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.48.114/24 brd 112.73.48.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.73.59.255/24 brd 112.73.59.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fec3:2987/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Interface configuration file (/etc/netplan/...):

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens2:
            addresses:
            - 10.101.0.48/24
            match:
                macaddress: 52:54:00:0b:a7:e5
            mtu: 1500
            routes:
            -   to: 10.0.0.0/8
                via: 10.101.0.1
            set-name: ens2
        ens3:
            addresses:
            - 157.119.73.25/25
            - 157.119.73.27/25
            - ...
            - 112.73.59.190/24  # Commented out during troubleshooting
            - 112.73.59.255/24
            match:
                macaddress: 52:54:00:c3:29:87
            mtu: 1500
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
            routes:
            -   to: 0.0.0.0/0
                via: 157.119.73.1
            set-name: ens3
```

After commenting out the line `- 112.73.59.190/24` in the interface configuration file and reapplying (`netplan apply`), the issue no longer persists. The `curl --interface 112.73.59.255 ip.sb` command now correctly returns the public IP `112.73.59.255`. This behavior remains consistent even after uncommenting the line and reapplying (`netplan apply`).

Comment: It's not recommend to use the network broadcast address as an host address, because of possible problems with legacy applications. See here: https://serverfault.com/questions/706860/is-there-any-harm-to-use-the-broadcast-ip-for-a-host

Comment: Sorry but using a *broadcast* address *as source* won't work, on *any* RFC-compliant OS. This line `inet 112.73.59.255/24 brd 112.73.59.255 scope global secondary ens3` is just a configuration error that isn't simply rejected. This is not a Linux problem. (Then in addition, a broadcast *destination* won't work for TCP, again whatever the OS. So a reply wouldn't work, unless the next hop router is configured to avoid considering it as a broadcast address, to spare one available IP address).